# Does Android Layout XML documentation exist?

Tags: android, xml, layout

I've soearched the docs at developer.android.com, and can't seem to find a place where the possible xml attributes and their values are defined for the various views, viewgroups, layouts etc. For instance, I'm here in android studio...
[android studio UI builder xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8ehc.png)
And I'd like to have a list of all the possible/appropriate attributes, and their sub-attributes, and what possible/appropriate values they might be able to accept. Like...

android:inputType="textPersonName"

There's "android", and "app", and "tools" in the first place, then "inputType" etc. What are the possible values for android:inputType:? Is there a complete list somewhere?

On the java side, we have the api reference which is thorough... at least it lists every method for every class etc., but I haven't found a one-stop-shop for the myriad xml options.

If it's the case that the javadoc has the info, but there's a naming/translation scheme that effectively implies the xml, that's ok but an actual list of all the options with descriptions of what they mean would be awesome.

Hopefully I just haven't searched the right terms yet. Any help much appreciated, I've been frustrated working with the xml. thank you!

I've searched the internet for a while, probably not enough, and I was expecting to find a comprehensive documentation site where I could search for something like EditText, and then find all the potential xml attributes, and for each of those, all the potential values, with descriptions of what they mean.

Answer (score 0):

> and can't seem to find a place where the possible xml attributes and their values are defined for the various views, viewgroups, layouts etc.

It is in the JavaDocs for the particular class in question.

For example, [the JavaDocs for `TextView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/widget/TextView) has a table towards the top named "XML Attributes". That information is also available in a list format, such as [this list for `TextView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/widget/TextView?hl=en#xml-attributes).

Comment: Thank you that's a big improvement. For EditText, there is one attribute android:enableTextStylingShortcuts, then I can go to TextView, and View, to see the inherited lists (using the links you suggested). However they are all "android:" attributes, and when working on android studio projects, I see "app:" and "tools:" as well, and not sure where to find the complete list. Also if I click on inputType, I get to the definition that it is an int. I don't yet see all the possible inputTypes with descriptions of what they mean. Where do I find the list of inputTypes (or values for any other att?)

Comment: @JayHurley: I don't know where `tools` all might be listed, though many of them simply duplicate `android` ones. For example, `tools:text` means the same as `android:text` but only applies to the IDE. `app` ones also are poorly documented.

Comment: I found TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PERSON_NAME, but how does that get associated (if indeed is is associated) with the attr value textPersonName? I guess if there's no official way to associate, we can hash it out here. Thanks again for any help.

Comment: @JayHurley: "I found TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PERSON_NAME, but how does that get associated (if indeed is is associated) with the attr value textPersonName?" -- in the source code of `TextView`, presumably.